# MariaDB absurdity using LAG function

Tags: select, mariadb, lag, mariadb-10.4

Absurdity happening.
Can someone help me with this?
When I comment out some non-logical part the result changes. Screenshots are provided on Navicat.

```
SELECT 

(1=1) 
AND 
(
    (LAG(l) OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY date) > 1 AND 1=1) 
OR (LAG(l) OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY date) > 1 AND 1=1)
)

AS is_fs FROM `aggregates` WHERE YEAR(date) = 2016 AND ticker = 'GFF' ORDER BY is_fs DESC
```

And the result is NULL.
While when commenting ***"(1=1) AND"***, the result becomes 1.
Or even worse, when I delete 2nd part of the OR (which is BTW identical to the first part) again the result becomes 1. Or even the worst: when I delete ***"PARTITION BY ticker"*** from the firts part of "OR" again the result appears.

How this is even possible... What am I missing ?

[image: Absurdity1]

[image: Absurdity2]

[image: Absurdity3]

[image: Data]

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: done, thank you

Comment: Can you provide some sample data or a link to a db-fiddle?

Comment: sure, uploaded the last image of data

Comment: Outside the scope of the question, but what *exactly* is it you're trying to do with all the rather meaningless `1=1`s in the query you've provided? Is this is a simplification of some other condition?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe in [this simplified DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iEoGYnnKA3pmkB9piu8pWk/0); the query you've provided above seems to work as expected. What MySQL version are you running? For instance, MySQL 5.7 doesn't support window functions at all, whereas MySQL 8 introduced them.

Comment: We can't cut and paste an image into a test case.

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table? This could be a bug related to indexes.

Comment: @esqew yes, it's simplification. it's for testing only.

Comment: @Barmar yes, sorry for the images. The indexes are date and ticker simple normal  btree

Comment: Can you save us all the effort and post a [mre] or a link to db-filddle?

Comment: @esqew I see you have done a great job (instead of me), thanks for trying to help. I see you have identical case and working. But still doesn't work on my machine. I have MariaDB 10-4. I have doubts that something with my mysql can appear to be. Will try to change the engine and check

Comment: @Barmar I am too sorry, I didn't do that. But someone from kind world like "esqew" user did. Can you see the comment above?

Comment: I would try repairing the table and indexes. Regardless, this is clearly a bug.

Comment: @Barmar , thanks for the help. Do you mean removing indexes and resetting again? It's InnoDB. Will try to research how to repair the correct way. Thanks.
Will update you

Comment: I was thinking of `REPAIR TABLE`, but that's not appropriate for InnoDB.

Comment: Try dropping and re-adding the indexes.

Comment: changed to MyISSAM, repaired, dropped indexes, and set again, even had a backup, deleted table and executed backup (even though there are almost 3M rows...), changed to MariaDB another version. Still the same...

Comment: FInally.
Changed to MySQL-8 engine and works like a charm. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Copied to MariaDB bug [MDEV-32349](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-32349)

Comment: When you solve the problem you should post it as an answer, not put SOLVED in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know the reason, but changing MariaDB to MySQL-8 solved the issue, after trying to repair, backup reinstall, index drop-set, etc...